# Windows 7 Style Help File?

Tags: windows-7, format

How does one make their application help file similar to the new windows 7 help format and is that compatible with Windows XP? Can anyone provide details ?

Can we use the windows 7 default viewer as a shell to our own help files????

Comment: Is that a .chm file? Complied HTML file? or a .hlp file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinXP only supports Complied HTML (.chm) and the really old .hlp format, if you need anything else on older platforms it might be possible to use the Document Explorer that MSDN uses/used (Not sure if there is a redistributable package without the MSDN stuff you can use)